# How to bind time in TimePicker Universal windows Platform?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

How to bind Time in `TimePicker`. When i try to bind time I get an FormatException error. How to convert to a format that the `TimePicker` will support?

Answer (score 2):

TimePicker.Time property is of type TimeSpan, So in order to bind to TimePicker's time property we need to convert datetime to timespan.

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{

  //Initialize someDateTime with a default value
  private DateTime someDateTime = DateTime.Parse("07/21/1969 2:56AM");

  public DateTime SomeDateTime
  {
    get { return someDateTime; }
    set { Set(ref someDateTime,value); }
  }

}}


public class DateTimeToTimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;            
        TimeSpan? ts = DateTimeConverter.DateTimeToTimeSpan(dt);
        return ts.GetValueOrDefault(TimeSpan.MinValue);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return TimeSpan.MinValue;
    }
}
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page ...>

   <Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
  </Page.DataContext>



<Page.Resources>
  <Converters:DateTimeToTimeSpanConverter
    x:Key="DateTimeToTimeSpanConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

  <!-- ... -->
  <TimePicker
    Header="My time"
    Margin="10" FontSize="24"
    Time="{Binding SomeDateTimeTime, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToTimeSpanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
  <!-- ... -->

</Page>
```

Comment: no i getting again   Exception . i need to Convert String to TimeSpan Format .can u Give me Suggestion.

Comment: i thing time picker Support  Only TimeSpan Format.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Exception Error :- String is not Correct Format

Comment: i have solved the problem easy convert and binded time in Time picker Control

Comment: yes, good job. i have edited my answer. date and time formatting depends on control, programming languages. And you need to follow the procedure. :)

Answer (score 0):

TimePicker.Time is a TimeSpan. You can set the Time using DateTime TimeOfDay property.

For example:

XAML:

```
<TimePicker Time="{Binding PickerTime}"/>
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
TimeSpan pickerTime = DateTime.Now.TimOfDay;
    ///PROPERTY
    public TimeSpan PickerTime {
        get { return pickerTime; }
        set {
            if(pickerTime != value) {
                pickerTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PickerTime");
            }
        }
    }
```